# Issue with Tomcat configurations using Docker

Tags: tomcat, docker

I have downloaded a tomcat image from docker hub and made three instance in an docker container of that tomcat . now issue is, I cant edit the configuration file of instances. so can anyone help me how can i edit the conf file to change server, http and ajp ports of the conf file and make instance according to my choice of ports so that i can make multiple instance in tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration can be edited, most of the images will not have nano / vi to edit,
install those and edit files.Enter into docker container

```
docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash
```

After changing configuration commit the container with new name.

If there is restriction for editing file, then run 3 instances of tomcat with different port binding.

```
docker run -itd -p 8080:8080 -p 8009:8009 tomcat /bin/bash

docker run -itd -p 9090:8080 -p 9009:8009 tomcat /bin/bash
```

...

So you can connect to specific tomcat using port exposed outside.